# Using JSP to write a widget generator to be used in other servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm new to JSP, so here's the problem. 
I want to create a block of HTML code with dynamism in it.
This block of code needs to be repeated/reused multiple times in multiple places on my site.
It's ugly to create a method with lots of

```
responseOut.println("<html> text with escaped characters")
```

So I'm wondering if JSP can be used to create reusable (callable or addressable by Class.methodname) methods.

It's easy to do this in PHP within the PHP framework.

I guess it all depends to the extent that JSP is s precompilation method? or run dynamically in the webserver...

I'm working in Eclipse (with GAE), so any comments and hints in this framework would also be appreciated.

Thanx
Dan

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate parts of Java (or JSP code) in tags that can be reused in other contexts. 
Have a look at [this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/JSP20/) for a first introduction.

Answer (score 0):

At its simplest, you can put it in a JSP fragment file and use `<jsp:include>` to include it. The "dynamism" can just be achieved using taglibs/EL. How exactly to do it depends on the sole functional requirement which is yet unclear. At least, HTML code does definitely not belong in a Servlet class.

However the statement `"<html> text with escaped characters"` makes me think that all you *really* need is the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:out>` tag. It will by default escape HTML entities like `<`, `>`, etc to prevent HTML code injection (and XSS holes).

Comment: So I can't add JSP functionality into a traditional servlet at the top level?